# Can I enter a range of coordinates when using turtle in an if statement?

Tags: python

I want to make an interactive calculator but I'm new to python. Using turtle I thought I would achieve this by using `onscreenclick()` within a particular range of coordinates for each calculator "button". I figured I could store the input into variables to carry out math operations and if statements

```
def buttonclick(x,y):
    if buttonclick ==
```

Here I want to use all coordinates from (5,0) to (65,-30)
Honestly I don't know if any of this actually makes sense, so if anyone has any suggestions, I will gladly take them.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for inequality expressions.

To check whether `x` is between 5 and 65 while `y` is between -30 and 0 (which means whether the point (`x`, `x`) is in the corresponding axis-aligned 60×30 rectangle), you can evaluate

```py
5 < x < 65 and -30 < y < 0
```

or, if you want the numbers int he order you listed them

```py
5 < x < 65 and 0 > y > -30
```

To include the borders of the rectangle you can use Python's operators equivalent to math's ≤ and ≥:

```py
5 <= x <= 65 and -30 <= y <= 0
```

or

```py
5 <= x <= 65 and 0 >= y >= -30
```

These are boolean expressions, so you can use them as the condition for an `if` statement.